# How to return multiple Service Bus messages from Azure Function?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, azureservicebus

Is there a way to output multiple `Message` (`ServiceBusMessage` in version 5.0) instances from an Azure Function? The documentation [says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output) that one can either return a single message via `out Message` or multiple entities via `ICollector<T>`/`IAsyncCollector<T>`.

I guess the `T` is a payload type, so using `ICollector<Message>` would not allow me to configure `SessionId` and other sending options. Instead, it would simply treat the `Message` as a payload within an actual message.

Comment: You can use `IAsyncCollector<ServiceBusMessage>`. Before adding a message to collection set the `SessionId`. Also for .Net 5, use `ServiceBusMessage` type instead of `Message` type. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=csharp#additional-types).

Comment: @user1672994 you are right, I just found [another example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.servicebus-readme-pre#sending-multiple-messages) of sending multiple messages that uses `IAsyncCollector<ServiceBusMessage>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user1672994 pointed out, both `ICollector<T>` and `IAsyncCollector<T>` accept `ServiceBusMessage` as the `T`. Here is [an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.servicebus-readme-pre#sending-multiple-messages) from Azure WebJobs Service Bus extension.

Comment: Dead link unfortunately. The search continues...

Comment: Too many pending edits, but here is the updated link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.servicebus-readme?view=azure-dotnet#sending-multiple-messages

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp5
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, 
            [ServiceBus("queuename1", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString1")] IAsyncCollector<dynamic> outputServiceBus1,
            [ServiceBus("queuename2", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString2")] IAsyncCollector<dynamic> outputServiceBus2,
            ILogger log)
        {
            await outputServiceBus1.AddAsync("xxx");

            await outputServiceBus2.AddAsync("xxx");

            return new OkObjectResult("This is a test.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have missed my point. There is only one queue. I need to configure my sending options, therefore have to return multiple `ServiceBusMessage` instances, not a payload.